# Doxygen: how to create documentation a chapter (for pdf) and how it would look in html?

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation

So I have this [little project of mine](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/) and I made it so that some of my servers automatically generate doxygen documentation in [PDF](http://195.19.243.13/documentation/cloud_observer_cpp_docs.pdf) form and [HTML](http://195.19.243.13/documentation/html/). When I look at pdf I see:

[image]

and when I look at HTML I see:

[image]

This means that main page I defined [here](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/main.cpp?r=2215) with something like `/*!  @mainpage CF Cloud Observer Server ...` is created.

I wonder how to create a chapter that would start after main documentation page (`CF Cloud Observer Server` chapter) and will not be part of it (say with tutorials called `CF CO Tutorials` after `CF Cloud Observer Server chapter` before `Module Documentation`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\page` command to create any number of additional pages. For example:

```
/**
 * \page tutorials CF CO Tutorials
 * A page containing Tutorial information.
 */
```

*If* you did want to create a sub page for a section, you can do that as well. In that case, you would specify the subpages in the parent page using the `\subpage` command, something like:

```
/**
 * \page tutorials CF CO Tutorials
 * A page containing Tutorial information.
 *
 * \subpage tutorial1
 */

/**
 * \page tutorial1 Tutorial 1
 * A subpage covering Tutorial 1
 */
```

In this case, `Tutorial 1` would now show up as a subpage of `CF CO Tutorials`.

You can find more information about the `\page`, `\subpage` commands as well as the related `\section` and `\subsection` commands [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html).